Node/Discord.js creating a Bot to automatic remove members from threads
Another day another project. Today I am using Node.js to create a Discord bot to automatically remove members from a Discord thread or post who lost the "view channel" permission to said category or parent channel.
Normally you would see a strike-through in the list of participants in the channel, then rightclick on the member and choose "Remove x from thread". Now the bot has to do this from ALL existing threads.
 import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } from 'discord.js';
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction],
});

const TOKEN = '**HIDDEN**';

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  // Check access for all existing threads
  try {
    await checkAllThreads();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error checking all threads:', error);
  }
});

async function checkMemberAccess(thread) {
  try {
    const members = await thread.members.fetch();
    const channel = thread.parent;

    members.forEach(async member => {
      const guildMember = await thread.guild.members.fetch(member.id);
      const hasAccessRole = guildMember.roles.cache.some(role => {
        return channel.permissionsFor(role).has('VIEW_CHANNEL');
      });

      if (!hasAccessRole) {
        await thread.members.remove(member.id);
        console.log(`Removed ${member.user.tag} from thread ${thread.name}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error checking thread members:', error);
  }
}

async function checkAllThreads() {
  client.guilds.cache.forEach(async guild => {
    try {
      const threads = await guild.threads.fetch();
      threads.forEach(async thread => {
        await checkMemberAccess(thread);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error checking threads for guild ${guild.name}:`, error);
    }
  });
}

client.on('threadCreate', thread => {
  // Check access when a new thread is created
  checkMemberAccess(thread);
});

client.login(TOKEN);

For obvious reasons I hid the token, the bot successfully connects and comes online. The problem I am having is that it is throwing an error code:
Logged in as thread#8061!
Error checking threads for guild T1MAT0's server: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
    at file:///home/runner/threadbot/index.js:49:43
    at _Collection.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at checkAllThreads (file:///home/runner/threadbot/index.js:47:23)
    at Client.<anonymous> (file:///home/runner/threadbot/index.js:19:11)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (/home/runner/threadbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:388:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (/home/runner/threadbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:371:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (/home/runner/threadbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:201:16)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:518:28)

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

You see this line const threads = await guild.threads.fetch(); Please try console.log the guild before this line as the error is saying that there is no threads property on the guild i.e. it's undefined...

@SharpDev gives the same error code, despite me adding "console.log(Checking threads in guild ${guild.name})"

No. just console.log the entire guild not just the name of the guild... Otherwise look at the documentation.

@SharpDev , console.log(Checking guild ${guild});
Resulted in no logs and the same error. If I am doing something wrong, please do give me a bit more background. I am not overly experienced in Node.js yet

looks like you thought ChatGPT wouldn't steer you wrong here... Unfortunately it has. With that said.... I'll give you a brief breakdown of what is happening: (You might even be able to tell chat gpt this lol): So the Guilds manager when accessed with cache (as you are doing) will have a channels manager The channels manager can be accessed the same way you access the guilds manager. Now the channels manager will have a threads manager for each thread in a channel. What you want to do is access the channels within your guild, and then for each of those access the threads in that channel.

@SharpDev , you were right that I used it to get me on my way for a good bit. Explaining it like the way you did sounds logical to me but not to a bot for sure. I tried a different approach to first identify all members of each thread, and this went okay until I added another person to my server and it malfunctioned Error logging threads and participants: RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: VIEW_CHANNEL.
I hope you may be able to suggest a different code, if not, I will wait until someone else can help me a bit further.
